# Need to SUM two columns in MySQL only if "Approved" = "Y"

Tags: mysql

I have the following working query that gives me the "Used_LeaveTimeSum".
[image]

```
SELECT     
SUM(lqHoursPL) AS Used_LeaveTimePL, 
SUM(lqHoursPB) AS Used_LeaveTimePB, 
SUM(lqHoursUL) AS Used_LeaveTimeUL, 
SUM(lqHoursFMLA) AS Used_LeaveTimeFMLA, 
COALESCE(SUM(lqHoursPL),0)+ COALESCE(SUM(lqHoursFMLA),0) AS Used_LeaveTimeSum

FROM      tblleaverequest
WHERE 
tblleaverequest.lqUser = 'jdoe' AND 
YEAR(tblleaverequest.lqStartDate) = YEAR(CURDATE())
```

Now I need to filter the sum to only "Approved records" so I changed the WHERE clause to:

```
WHERE 
lqApproved = "Y" AND
tblleaverequest.lqUser = 'jdoe' AND 
YEAR(tblleaverequest.lqStartDate) = YEAR(CURDATE())
```

Now all I get is all zero's?
[image]

Here is the backend data: ("Used_LeaveTimeSum" should be 24)
[image]

INSERT INTO `tblleaverequest` (`lqID`, `lqUser`, `lqSupervisor`, `lqTotalHours`, `lqHoursPL`, `lqHoursPB`, `lqHoursUL`, `lqHoursFMLA`, `lqStartDate`, `lqEndDate`, `lqDescription`, `lqNotes`, `lqSubmitted`, `lqApproved`, `lqCreated`, `lqmodified`, `lqmodifiedBy`) VALUES (392, 'jdoe', 'jsmith', 8, 8, 0, 0, 0, '2017-01-02', '2017-01-02', '* Testing - Please Disregard* Upd', NULL, 'Y', 'Y', '2017-01-05 16:13:08', '2017-01-12 09:00:29', 'jdoe');
INSERT INTO `tblleaverequest` (`lqID`, `lqUser`, `lqSupervisor`, `lqTotalHours`, `lqHoursPL`, `lqHoursPB`, `lqHoursUL`, `lqHoursFMLA`, `lqStartDate`, `lqEndDate`, `lqDescription`, `lqNotes`, `lqSubmitted`, `lqApproved`, `lqCreated`, `lqmodified`, `lqmodifiedBy`) VALUES (427, 'jdoe', 'jsmith', 8, 8, 0, 0, 0, '2017-01-12', '2017-01-12', '* Testing - Please Disregard* ', NULL, 'Y', 'Y', '2017-01-11 09:51:31', '2017-01-12 09:01:08', NULL);
INSERT INTO `tblleaverequest` (`lqID`, `lqUser`, `lqSupervisor`, `lqTotalHours`, `lqHoursPL`, `lqHoursPB`, `lqHoursUL`, `lqHoursFMLA`, `lqStartDate`, `lqEndDate`, `lqDescription`, `lqNotes`, `lqSubmitted`, `lqApproved`, `lqCreated`, `lqmodified`, `lqmodifiedBy`) VALUES (428, 'jdoe', 'jsmith', -8, -8, 0, 0, 0, '2017-01-11', '2017-01-11', '* Testing - Please Disregard* ', NULL, 'Y', 'Y', '2017-01-11 09:56:02', '2017-01-12 09:00:33', NULL);
INSERT INTO `tblleaverequest` (`lqID`, `lqUser`, `lqSupervisor`, `lqTotalHours`, `lqHoursPL`, `lqHoursPB`, `lqHoursUL`, `lqHoursFMLA`, `lqStartDate`, `lqEndDate`, `lqDescription`, `lqNotes`, `lqSubmitted`, `lqApproved`, `lqCreated`, `lqmodified`, `lqmodifiedBy`) VALUES (422, 'jdoe', 'jsmith', 8, 8, 0, 0, 0, '2017-01-11', '2017-01-11', '* Testing - Please Disregard* ', NULL, 'Y', 'Y', '2017-01-10 14:43:58', '2017-01-12 09:00:35', NULL);
INSERT INTO `tblleaverequest` (`lqID`, `lqUser`, `lqSupervisor`, `lqTotalHours`, `lqHoursPL`, `lqHoursPB`, `lqHoursUL`, `lqHoursFMLA`, `lqStartDate`, `lqEndDate`, `lqDescription`, `lqNotes`, `lqSubmitted`, `lqApproved`, `lqCreated`, `lqmodified`, `lqmodifiedBy`) VALUES (423, 'jdoe', 'jsmith', 8, 8, 0, 0, 0, '2017-01-09', '2017-01-09', '* Testing - Please Disregard* ', NULL, 'Y', 'Y', '2017-01-10 14:51:25', '2017-01-12 09:04:56', NULL);
INSERT INTO `tblleaverequest` (`lqID`, `lqUser`, `lqSupervisor`, `lqTotalHours`, `lqHoursPL`, `lqHoursPB`, `lqHoursUL`, `lqHoursFMLA`, `lqStartDate`, `lqEndDate`, `lqDescription`, `lqNotes`, `lqSubmitted`, `lqApproved`, `lqCreated`, `lqmodified`, `lqmodifiedBy`) VALUES (426, 'jdoe', 'jsmith', 8, 8, 0, 0, 0, '2017-01-11', '2017-01-11', '* Testing - Please Disregard* ', NULL, 'Y', 'N', '2017-01-11 09:42:04', '2017-01-11 09:42:26', NULL);

Comment: Please provide data as formated text and not as a image..

Comment: Is it possible that in your data there is a space after the Y?

Comment: are you sure you have a column [lqUser] with values ['jdoe'] I can't see in the image

Comment: If that is really the actual data AND the only thing in the query that has changed is the addition of `lqApproved = "Y"`, then the value of `lqApproved` must be different than what you think it is .. Check the distinct values and sizes: `SELECT DISTINCT lqApproved, length(lqApproved) AS LenlqApproved FROM YourTable`

Comment: Why is this question tagged as ColdFusion?

Comment: Thanks for the responses:

Comment: There could be an issue with using the double quotes in the lqApproved = "Y"  clause depending on the server settings.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11321491/when-to-use-single-quotes-double-quotes-and-backticks-in-mysql

Comment: Thanks again,
- The "lqApproved" column is Datatype: VARCHAR, Length: 1
- I updated original post to include the raw data
- I tried the query with single quotes, double quotes, no quotes.. no change?
ps: This query is part of my CFQUERY dataset on my ColdFusion page.

Comment: Got it! I changed the = to LIKE and it started working?
    lqApproved LIKE "Y"

Thanks for the help.